# QR code generation algorithm data masking implementation case analysis

Tags: c++, algorithm, qr-code

I'm implementing a QR code generation algorithm as explained on [thonky.com](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/) and I'm trying to understand one of the cases:

As stated on [this page](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/data-masking/), after getting the percentage of the dark modules out of the whole code, I should take the two nearest multiples of five (for example *45* and *50* for *48%*), but what if the percentage is a multiple of 5? for example 45.0? what numbers should be taken? 45? 40 and 50? 45 and 40? 45 and 50? something totally different? I couldn't find any answer to that anywhere...

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the Thonky tutorial is unclear in this respect, so let's turn to the official standard (behind a paywall at ISO but [easy to find online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=iso+18004+filetype%3Apdf&ia=web)). Section 8.8.2, page 52, Table 24:

> Evaluation condition: 50 ± (5 × k)% to 50 ± (5 × (k + 1))%
>   Points: N₄ × k

Here, N₄ = 10, and

> k is the rating of the deviation of the proportion of dark modules in the symbol from 50% in steps of 5%.

So for for exactly 45% dark modules, you'd have k = 1, resulting in a penalty of 10 points.

Also note that it doesn't really matter if you get this slightly wrong. Because the mask pattern identifier is encoded in the format string, a reader can still decode the QR code even if you accidentally chose a slightly suboptimal mask pattern.